Visual Studio- Strip PDB file path from static library
I'm trying to remove the PDB path in order not to expose my computer's internal directory structure in libraries that are going to be distributed publicly.
In EXE and and DLL files I can specify "/PDBALTPATH:%_PDB%" in the linker command line to do this, but the librarian tool seems to completely ignore this and still includes the paths.
I would appreciate any insights regarding that.

Visual Studio cannot load symbols from a static library used on a module of the main application

the static libraries does not have a pdb file associated with them
(when debugging). The code being added to the main application exe,
the symbols are also merged with the main.

To verify this, you can delete the pdb files of the static and dynamic libraries and then debug the exe.  F11 will skip the functions of the dynamic library. While the static library will be able to hit the breakpoint.

I'm checking the lib files in HxD. They definitely contain the paths of the project files. I need to have those removed...
